# I take it that this site is not the place to ask a question about a news story regarding corporate tax fraud. Where should I go?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Which site might be better to ask a question about the implications of a corporation inflating the cost of a product that they donate to charity?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ask about the implications on an individual from a personal finance perspective it could be on topic as long as it isn't asking to start a discussion thread or polling for opinions.

Otherwise, maybe you would be better posting it on a finance discussion board. I'm not aware of any site on the SE network where this would be on topic.